# Cannot add item to cart in magento with two store

Tags: php, magento

thanks for reading.

I have a magento site that has two store in it. Retail and wholesale.

I'm not able to add any item to the cart it shows blank page.

The error is this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Weee_Helper_Data::setStore() in /var/www/vhosts/club27clothing.com/club27clothing.com/app/code/core/Mage/Weee/Model/Total/Quote/Weee.php on line 93
```

Compilation is disabled, cache cleared and refreshed. Magento version is 1.8 and Community edition.

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks.

Comment: Please check Mage_Wee module is enable or not...

Answer (score 0):

Sort it myself. This file or module is different in 1.8.0 than 1.8.1. I manually uploaded some core files by mistake and I turned back to 1.8.0 as it was before it fixed the problem. Thank.s